# jQuery datepicker selecting the day before only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm using wordpress, with this plugin:

https://pinpoint.world/wordpress/documentation/

and I have a datepicker here: http://test.pappas.pe/en/availability/#

When I select a date the first time it formats it to the day before, but after that it works ok.

the function that creates the date picker its this:

```
$(id).datepicker({altField: altId,
                              altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                              beforeShow: function(input, inst){
                                $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('DOPBSPSearch-datepicker')
                                                       .addClass('DOPBSPSearch-datepicker');
                              },
                              dateFormat: methods_search.data['dateType'] === 1 ? 'MM dd, yy':'dd MM yy',
                              dayNames: methods_days.text['names'],
                              dayNamesMin: methods_days.text['shortNames'],
                              firstDay: methods_days.data['first'],
                              minDate: minDate,
                              monthNames: methods_months.text['names'],
                              monthNamesMin: methods_months.text['shortNames'],
                              nextText: methods_months.text['nextMonth'],
                              prevText: methods_months.text['previousMonth']});
```

It happens to me on windows, on chrome, and firefox, but not on mac on safari?? I'm really lost on this one.

Comment: To debug I'd remove all of the attributes in your config object and see if it works then (no redirect). Then I'd add each attribute in from altField to prevText in 1 at a time until you find the one that causes the weird affect.

Comment: Likely a timezone issue. Please include a [mcve] to reproduce the issue in the question, not on a third party site.